# HTML email signature showing up as raw html code

Tags: html, email, electronic-signature

I've created an HTML email signature, which **displays fine by itself in a browser** but when I paste it as my signature in my email client (*roundcube*) ***all the recipient of my email sees is the raw html code***.

I tried adding *body* tags but am unable to come up with a solution.
*Am I missing something* simple, as I haven't coded an HTML signature before.

The structure of the signature is simple and is basically:

```
<div>

 <img></img>
 <p></p>
 <p></p>

</div>
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question in response to answers.

Comment: Which client are you using? How did you add the signature? Also, this probably isn't a coding issue, so SO is probably not the best place for this question...

Comment: The client's called roundcube (thought it was called webmail). The client has a setting to put your signature in. And for all I know this isn't working because I'm missing some basic semantics. If it's supposed to work with the layout I've illustrated please let me know so I can troubleshoot other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

image is self closing `<img />` in stead of `<img></img>`

Comment: Right, don't know why I did that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my client along with some other no doubt aren't capable of displaying html code. So I have to stick with a boring plain signature.